# How to read Y-component from H264 4:2:0 video without default YUV2RGB->RGB2GRAY conversion

Tags: opencv, video, opencl, h.264

I need fast work with gray-scale frames hence I need only Y-component from YUV 4:2:0 video I have. As I can see from profiler a lot of time is wasting for useless YUV->RGB conversion.

```
VideoCapture::cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, false)
```

gives no effect, as I can see from splitting

```
Mat ch[3]; split(frame,ch); imshow("it must be U-channel", ch[1]);
```

frames is still in RGB, not YUV, i.e. VideoCapture **ignores** CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB flag (I believe ffmpeg library which is used by openCV for video-decoding can understand such kind of flags).

So, please, does someone have idea how to get gray-scaled image from video sequence faster? OpenCL methods are ok too since I convert Mat to oclMat to process this frames after reading ( including current useless ocl::cvtColor(A, B, CV_RGB2GRAY) ).

Comment: Do you process regular video file? No CV involved?

Comment: Yes, it is one of 100-s of regular video files I have -- just 1-2 hours movie from the Internet. No CV involved. And I know for sure it is encoded by ffmpeg. Have you ever got effect from CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB flag working with any of 4:2:0 movie? As I found here this [problem for camera is the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881299/get-grayscale-image-directly-from-webcam-using-opencv).

Answer (score 2):

For regular video decoding you don't need OpenCV. It can be done with ffmpeg library. Download & build latest version of ffmpeg & take a look at [sample](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/api-example_8c-source.html), in which you need `video_decode_example` function. In it's body, at line 401:

```
if (got_picture) {
    printf("saving frame %3d\n", frame);
    fflush(stdout);

    /* the picture is allocated by the decoder. no need to free it */
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), outfilename, frame);
    pgm_save(picture->data[0], picture->linesize[0], c->width, c->height, buf);
    frame++;
}
```

As ffmpeg works with Y Cb Cr color representation, Y plane of decoded frame is stored in `picture->data[0]`. Copy it to your OpenCL memory object, and that's it.

Comment: Yes, I saw [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953729/opencl-video-processing) before I asked my question, thank you. Sure ffmpeg lib is a decision. But using openCV functions only is more convenient, and it uses opencv_ffmpeg.dll anyway. Well, seems there no openCV-only-way, at least as long as [this bug](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3909) is opened (I am still not sure if it is really bug). I vote your answer as useful, but believe someone will teach us openCV-only-way for this issue.